# How can I add a link to my app on the homescreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-applications

On iphone my native app has an URL, so that if you type an url starting with `myapp://` it will open my app and it will handle the URL and go to the relevant place.

Is there a way to get these urls as a web app bookmark on the iphone's homescreen?

EDIT: To put it another way, I want add a webapp to link to my native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add Web Clips without going into Safari, and to specify a custom URL. But the Apple docs say that Web Clips will only work if the protocol is http or https (i.e. not `my app://`)

Comment: Having said this, the settings icons that have been in the 'news' recently are web clips that are not http/s protocol, and they still work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Never will be, as duplicates may occur then, e.g. two web apps with `goatse://…`, as Apple cannot check web apps.

Comment: @Radek, but conflicts can happen already, if my app chooses say `fb://` there will be conflict with the facebook app.

Comment: Your app will not be approved by Apple if that has already been taken. Conflicts are only possible on jailbroken devices or in the development phase of an app. Not in the App Store.

Comment: @Radek, in your answer you said Apple don't check, and now you say they do?

Comment: Apple checks apps in the app store. Apple doesn't check web apps as that is impossible. That's what I said :)

Comment: @RadekS: Yes, but I want to create a web app which is just the url `myapp://` so that when a user taps the web app it opens my native app not safari.

Comment: Why create a web app that opens another app when they can just open that other app in the first place??